# Rails 3 file_store caching, delete expired fragments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have a Rails 3.2.11 application running on Unicorn and is set up for file_store caching to a specific folder outside of the project.
I am also using the gem [rails/cache_digests](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests) for automatic expiration.
In a certain page I'm doing fragment caching without setting time expiration.

When a fragment has expired, I see the new fragment created in the cache folder, but I also see the expired fragment as well. How it will be deleted from the cache folder by the cache management mechanism without doing it manually? If it doesn't get deleted then the cache folder will be bloated with garbage, expired fragments that are not used.

Comment: you have to do it explicitly with `expire_fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this [cleanup](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d107a842dd3ce28c278175fac7344549dabb5c38/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb#L30) function to delete all the expired fragments. And you may set up a script to run this command periodically.

Comment: let cache(posts, current_user)
how can we get all cache keys for all fragments for all combinations of collection of posts, current_users and versions of view includes previous versions?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [ActionController::Caching::Sweeping](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping) to expire fragment cache.

See below example:

```
class ProductSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  #expire fragment after model update
  def after_save
   expire_fragment('all_available_products')   
  end

  #expire different cache after controller method modifying state is called.
  def after_products_update_some_state
    expire_action(:controller => 'products', :action => 'index') 
  end

  #can also use before:
  def before_products_update_some_state
    #do something before. 
  end
end
```

This [url](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_1-caching_strategies/) is also help you

Comment: no, we can`t.
for fragment(products) we have digest
and when we want to expire fragment after product update we don`t know this digest